# Cannot get context-param in web.xml from Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a simple webapp which use Spring Boot web and 
I have a web.xml file in 
`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` which contains context-param like this

```
<context-param>
    <description>Directory containing the configuration files</description>
    <param-name>confDir</param-name>
    <param-value>/opt/rasdaman/etc/</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In Servlet Controller, I could get the Servlet Context

```
@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;
```

but when I tried to get the parameter, it returns null

```
servletContext.getInitParameter("confDir");
```

when I tried to get the real path to the servletContext

```
servletContext.getRealPath(File.separator);
```

it returns

```
 "..../src/main/webapp/"
```

How can I get the configuration variable in web.xml?

Thanks

Comment: why not put your param in the property file?

Comment: it is a legacy source which use web.xml configuration so I could not move to other file.

Answer (score 1):

Havent tried it myself but. If you make a Controller implement ServletContextAware I think you can get your context-param from : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html

The idea would be

```
public class MyCoolController implements ServletContextAware {


    @Override
    setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        String confDir = servletContext.getInitParameter("confDir");
    }
}
```

Give it a shot

Comment: Are you deploying your app as a war file?

Comment: it is a jar file as Spring Boot starts like this

public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(ApplicationMain.class, args);

Comment: You should probably take a look at this then https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Comment: I tried change to war and add dependency as http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging for maven but also still null for configuration variable in web.xml.

Comment: When your war is packaged. Do you see your web.xml inside the war file in the appropriate directory?

Comment: you have a perfect suggestion, only war file can load web.xml and I mixed up with the old pom so fix it correctly and it can show the configuration variable, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [sudakatux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137417/sudakatux) the problem is I used deploy Spring Boot with jar not war then cannot read from web.xml

follow [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) to change to war and deploy with tomcat EE normally